# How can I use XPath to resolve the following 'tags' values?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

The xml file is :

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:xyz="http://someurl">
   <xyz:xyzcontent>
     <contentattribute>
       <key>tags</key>
       <value>tag1, tag2</value>
     </contentattribute>
   </xyz:xyzcontent>
...
```

I've tried the following:

```
XPathExpression createdDateExpression = xpath.compile("/contentattribute/key/attribute::tags/value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your query.

- The XML is broken (root tag not closed) -- probably just a copy/paste mistake
- You're starting somewhere right in the middle of the XML tree, but actually try to query from the root node. Use the descendant-or-self-axis `//` in the beginning.
- Which attribute are you querying using the `attribute`-axis? There is none.
- Where did you register the namespaces? What namespace is `xyz`, anyway? I guess it's actually `vp`, but you obfuscated incompletely (or are not giving all relevant parts of the document).
- Use predicates and string comparison to filter at axis steps.

Try following:

- Make sure to register the namespace, have a look at the reference for that (or give more information).
- Use the XPath query `//contentattribute[key='tags']/value`